# How to show Data Use "Stored Procedure (Exec) Query SQL Server" codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

CI_Controller ..

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('model_contoh');
    $data = $this->model_contoh->GetDataByProc();
    echo '<pre>' ;
    print_r($data->result_array());     
}
}
```

CI_Model ..

```
function GetDataByProc(){

$data = $this->db->query("spCekSelisihJurnal '1/1/2018 00:00:00','12/31/2018 23:00:00'"); 

return $data ; }}
```

***if this query execute in sql tool success to show the data
but not run in codeigniter ?***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuHZn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you not call like this. P1 and P2 would need to need procedure parameter names

```
$p_1 = '1/1/2018 00:00:00'
$p_2 = '12/31/2018 23:00:00'
$stored_procedure = "CALL spCekSelisihJurnal(?,?) ";
$result = $this->db->query($stored_pocedure,array('P1'=>$p_1,'P2'=>$p_2));
```

Comment: if use CALL query not work but if not use call quey it work but no result .